# Problems with using Voice Interactions with new API 23

Tags: android

I'm working with new Voice Interaction API. I've read document at google developer but something and run example at http://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/voice-interaction. From that demo code, have something which I'm not clear

1. The demo camera app use to Google App to start app through voice interaction. How can i start app by different method with voice interaction?
2. The demo app started by using command "Take a selfie" in Google App. How do I customize this command?

Hope your help!!!